# Mouse over error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm actually using images for my header menu. I include mouseover and mouseout effects. In order for the selected menu to stay active I used session[id] in the image as well as the page itself.

like this...

```
<td>
            <a href="index.php?mid=1"><img border=0 src="images/orange_header_07.png" onmouseout="<?php if(isset($mid)&&($mid=1))
            {?>
                this.src='images/brown_header_02.png';
            <?php }else{
            ?>this.src='images/orange_header_07.png';<?php }?>" onmouseover="this.src='images/orange_header_07.png';" width="124" height="58" alt=""></a>
</td>
```

and in the page...

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['mid']=$_GET['mid'];
```

It works ,however when I simply hover my mouse on any other menu while on different page, it takes the mouse over effect. But when I mouseout it doesn't change back.

For instance I'm on Home page.The Home image on menu stays active and that's okay .But when  I simply hover on other menu like About us  or Contact us while on Home page, they showing the image for mouseover and when I take the mouse out, it's not changing to mouse out image.

I couldn't figure out my mistake. Can anyone point out please?

Comment: `$mid=1` is assignment. You want `$mid==1`

Comment: Yes i also think @meagar is right.

Comment: @meagar Thanks a lot for pointing out this silly mistake.